# ubuntu doesn't boot after installing quadro drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 13.10

so I installed a 2nd graphic card, installed the proprietary driver for it (nvidia quadro), but now when I boot the computer, the purple screen loads for a while and then all I get it's a black screen with a blinking cursor.
I've taken the 2nd card out but it doesn't change anything.

I am preparing a usb stick to boot from it and try to access my system: is there anything I can do to fix this?

it's a ubuntu 13.10 64 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, I found out shortly after posting, thanks to this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/352099/16726

1. enter recovery mode (keep left <kbd>shift</kbd> pressed, after BIOS is loaded, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> from black screen and `sudo su`)
2. `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`
3. `shutdown -r now`